# nloptr version 1.2.1 installation on Window 10: error #include "nlopt.h"

Tags: r, windows-10, devtools

I need to install `nloptr` version 1.2.1 on Windows 10. Here is my code:

```
library("devtools")
install_version("nloptr", version = "1.2.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

And here is extract of error message:

```
init_nloptr.c:35:10: fatal error: nlopt.h: No such file or directory
 #include "nlopt.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Any work around?

Comment: My guess is that you don't have nlopt installed on your machine. Nloptr is an interface to the program nlopt, which is primarily implemented in C and FORTRAN. So, you may need to install the software nlopt first, then try installing the nloptr package in R. Try here: https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_on_Windows/

Comment: @John Thank you! Do you know why `nloptr` version 1.2.2.2 installs without any problems and version 1.2.1 requires `nlopt` installed first?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know. I put this as a comment and not an answer primarily because I am uncertain if this is actually the issue, which given that you can install the newer version, it may be the case that I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, when installing {nloptr} from source on Windows OS, `'NLopt'` is required. See the description from its [github source](https://github.com/jyypma/nloptr):

> For this to work on Windows, you need to have Rtools and NLopt installed, and set an environment variable NLOPT_HOME with the location of the NLopt library.

This can be done through RTools. Just open "Rtools Bash" program and execute these lines:

```sh
pacman -Sy
pacman -S mingw-w64-{i686,x86_64}-nlopt
```

Note: `pacman -Sy` is required only for refreshing Rtools packages for the first time use of "pacman".

For more information, see [the official instructions of pacman](https://github.com/r-windows/docs/blob/master/rtools40.md#readme).